# Difference between 'lattice' and ''diagram'

Tags: meaning, grammar, differences

I would like to know the difference between 'lattice' and 'diagram' in mathematics context.

Comment: Possibly this is not the appropriate place to ask this question.

Comment: Isn't a mathematical lattice a particular kind of formally structured diagram?

Comment: @Rattler Can you share with me where is the best place? Do you advise math exchange?